# How to start IE in private mode in c# with selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I'm starting using selenium Webdriver with c# and Visualstudio.

I would like to start Internetexplorer in private mode. So I have not to care about old browsing data during my test.

I searched for quite a long time now to find how to do this. 
Sadly I could not find a solution.

Could anybody provide me with a working code snippet showing how to start IE in private mode from c# code?

I used the following command to start the browser normally:

```
Context.Instance.Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

I tried to add this to make it work:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "--private";
Context.Instance.Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

This was niether a success.

Finally, I tried this also:

```
InternetExplorerDriverService service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
options.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private";

Context.Instance.Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service, options);
```

I would like to have IE running in private mode for my tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, [InternetExplorerOptions Members](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_IE_InternetExplorerOptions.htm) page; it is stated that `BrowserCommandLineArguments` property only has an effect when the `ForceCreateProcessApi` is true. ForceCreateProcessApi default value is false.

Would you please try to set it manually?

```
options.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;
options.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private";
```

Comment: Hi tafa, and how the wedriver of selenium connect to it? This will not just start the process but without selenium?

Comment: Sorry, I know almost nothing about selenium webdriver. If you can update the question and post the code you have tried so far, you may get a better answer.

Comment: Hi Tafa, thanks for your additonal input. It works with some registry changes. I documented them to show the complete solution. Your input have been helpful!

Comment: hi DRK, Can you please share the steps to launch IE in private mode.

Comment: Also if you have an idea to launch IE in Enterprise mode?

Comment: Hi Tafa, the first snippet in your answer (Process.Start("iexplore.exe -private");) is misleading, as it doesn't work with Selenium. I suggest to remove it from the answer. Thanks!