# Running Internet Explorer selenium web driver in private mode c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm building UI automation tests using selenium, and I want to test our product with internet explorer browser. I'm trying to create InternetExplorerDriver using selenium 3.4.

But when I set the options to run in private mode, the IE browser doesn't launch. The options I set are:

```
ForceCreateProcessApi = true,

BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private".

private IWebDriver CreateInternetExplorerDriver()
    {
        InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
        {
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
            IgnoreZoomLevel = true,
            InitialBrowserUrl = "about:InPrivate",
            EnsureCleanSession = true,
            BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private",
            ForceCreateProcessApi = true
        };

        // Create a webdriver instance to automate the browser.
        return new InternetExplorerDriver(_webDriverDirectory, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DriverCommandTimeout * 3));
    }
```

The code run in VS 2017, windows 10 ,64-bit, and try to run Internet explorer driver 32-bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start IE in private mode in c# with selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423773/how-to-start-ie-in-private-mode-in-c-sharp-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I tried the options that suggested in the answer but it doesn't work. maybe the version has changed since then

Comment: Ah, ok makes sense

Comment: What version of the IE driver is it?

Comment: IEDriverServer_Win32_3.9.0

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using  IEDriverServer_x64_3.8.0. probably bug in the 3.9 and the 32 bit versions